# Getting pro guard parseException expecting java type before <em>Annotation</em>

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am getting pro guard parse exception while generating signed apk. It is saying proguardparseException expecting java type before 

Annotation

it says expecting java type before 
-keepattributes  Annotation

Below is my proguard.pro file code:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\anand\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#Basic proguard rules
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes <em>Annotation</em>
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keep class *<em>.R$</em>

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-forceprocessing
-optimizationpasses 5
-overloadaggressively

#Removing logging code
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** e(...);
}

#The -dontwarn option tells ProGuard not to complain about some artefacts in the Scala runtime

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { <em>; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.</em>*
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, <em>Annotation</em>
```

Comment: were you able to solve it? please comment your answer